# Edit mysql table in PHP on a LAMP stack

Tags: php, mysql, post, amazon-ec2, lamp

I'm trying to create a page to modify a MySQL database using PHP. I'm having trouble debugging the code. I am not displaying the full table on the "select to edit" page:

Main page: project_editsurvey10.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Noor's Beach Survey Edit Page</title>
    <link href="resources/css/beachsurvey.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/project_extra.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gradientbackground">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">EDIT DATA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
            <?php
            require 'project_db.php';
            mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
            mysql_select_db("$database")or die("cannot select DB");
            $order = "SELECT * FROM $table";
            $result = mysql_query($order);
            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
              echo "<tr><td>$row[Name]</td>";
              echo "<td>$row[Gender]</td>";
              echo "<td>$row[Website]</td>";
              echo "<td>$row[Email]</td>";
              echo "<td><a href=\edit_form.php
                emailupdate=$row[Email]\>Edit</a></td></tr>";
            }
            ?>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Form used to edit: edit_form.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Noor's Beach Survey Edit Data</title>
    <link href="resources/css/beachsurvey.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/project_extra.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gradientbackground">
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Edit Your Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
            <?php
            require 'project_db.php';
            mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
            mysql_select_db("$database")or die("cannot select DB");
            $emailupdate = $_GET["emailupdate"];

            $order = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE Email='$emailupdate'";
            $result = mysql_query($order);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            ?>
            <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="emailupdate" value="<?php echo "$row[Email]"?>" />
                <tr>
                    <td>Name: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo"$row[Name]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Website: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Website" value="<?php echo"$row[Website]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Gender" value="<?php echo"$row[Gender]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Country where the beach is located: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBCountry" value="<?php echo"$row[FBCountry]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>City where the beach is located: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBCity" value="<?php echo"$row[FBCity]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Favorite feature: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBFeature" value="<?php echo"$row[FBFeature]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cleanliness: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBClean" value="<?php echo"$row[FBClean]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Crowdedness: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBCrowd" value="<?php echo"$row[FBCrowd]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Types of people commonly seen: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBPeople" value="<?php echo"$row[FBPeople]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Wildlife: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBWildlife" value="<?php echo"$row[FBWildlife]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Backdrop scenery: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBBackdrop" value="<?php echo"$row[FBBackdrop]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Common waves: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBWaves" value="<?php echo"$row[FBWaves]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Seabed type: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBSeabed" value="<?php echo"$row[FBSeabed]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Average water temperature: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBTemp" value="<?php echo"$row[FBTemp]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Available amenities: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBAmenities" value="<?php echo"$row[FBAmenities]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Comments: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FBComment" value="<?php echo"$row[FBComment]"?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit value" value="Edit"></td>
                </tr>
            </form>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Editing function file: edit_data.php

```
    <?php
require 'project_db.php';
mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$database")or die("cannot select DB");

$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Website = $_POST['Website'];
$Gender = $_POST['Gender'];
$FBCountry = $_POST['FBCountry'];
$FBCity = $_POST['FBCity'];
$FBFeature = $_POST['FBFeature'];
$FBClean = $_POST['FBClean'];
$FBCrowd = $_POST['FBCrowd'];
$FBPeople = $_POST['FBPeople'];
$FBWildlife = $_POST['FBWildlife'];
$FBBackdrop = $_POST['FBBackdrop'];
$FBWaves = $_POST['FBWaves'];
$FBSeabed = $_POST['FBSeabed'];
$FBTemp = $_POST['FBTemp'];
$FBAmenities = $_POST['FBAmenities'];
$FBComment = $_POST['FBComment'];


$order = "UPDATE $table
        SET Name = '" . $UName . "',  Website = '" . $UWebsite . "', Gender = '" . $UGender . "',
            FBCountry = '" . $UFBCountry . "', FBCity = '" . $UFBCity . "', FBFeature = '" . $UFBFeature . "',
            FBClean = '" . $UFBClean . "', FBCrowd = '" . $UFBCrowd . "', FBPeople = '" . $UFBPeople . "',
            FBWildlife = '" . $UFBWildlife . "', FBBackdrop = '" . $UFBBackdrop . "', FBWaves = '" . $UFBWaves . "',
            FBSeabed = '" . $UFBSeabed . "', FBTemp = '" . $UFBTemp . "', FBAmenities = '" . $UFBAmenities . "',
            FBComment = '" . $UFBComment . "'
       WHERE Email = '". $emailupdate ."'";
mysql_query($order);
header("location:project_editsurvey10.php");
?>
```

Comment: Please specify what isn't happening that you want to happen or what is happening that is incorrect behaviour, and any pertinent error messages.

Comment: Stop using short tags. They have been disabled by default for the last several major releases of php.

Comment: Thank you, that with minor syntax modifications fixed the 2 webpages, however when I click the "Edit" button on EDIT_FORM.PHP it loops back to PROJECT_EDITSURVEY10.PHP without updating the records. It doesn't invoke the third file EDIT_DATA.PHP.